# CartoDB: Geometry code too long, Excel can't handle it

Tags: carto, geometry, import, excel

I am working on a map of regions where I want to be able to visualize some simple numbers on a periodical basis.

I have [a dataset with the polygons](https://michalmatlon.cartodb.com/tables/region_polygons) . However those are so detailed (the geometry is incredibly long), that when I export the dataset to .csv in order to add the additional data needed in Excel (and this will be done on a regular basis), it converts to invalid code that cannot be imported.

I tried copying the geometry manually, but the limit of an Excel cell is some 35 000 characters, while one polygon in this dataset has around 150 000 characters.

What can I do to be able to store the geometry in Excel and be able to import it when I need to update the numbers I want to visualise?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround that can solve your problem. You can create a new dataset (in CartoDB, Excel or another spreedsheet software) with the same number of rows (19), add the extra columns with the values you need. And then merge the `region_polygons` dataset with this new dataset. [Here](https://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/merging_data/) you have a tutorial about how to merge two datasets.

Comment: The problem is, the value can't fit in an Excel cell. And when pasting it into new CartoDB dataset, it gives me an error while saving it, presumably because of the massive length.

So the only way would be to create a final dataset in Excel and import it. But there is the cell character limit.

Comment: You do not have to download your polygon dataset. Follow this steps: 1st- Create a table in Excel, OpenOffice or even CartoDB. This new dataset will contain a column shared with the polygon one and any other additional ones. 2nd-Add a column in your original dataset with the same name and values as the one we have just created. 3rd Merge these two datasets using the Column join option, thus selecting the new_column and choosing the columns you would like to add.